# Why does Excel VBA sometimes highlight cells in Powerpoint Tables when changing font size

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am using Excel VBA to copy tables from a workbook into Powerpoint, and I'm using:

```
Shape.Table.Rows.Cell.Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 20
```

to format the font size of the cells. However, on one computer, this function highlights the content of the cells to change the font size (similar to how you would highlight text to change font size by hand), and on a different computer, this line of code changes the font sizes without needing to highlight the actual text. Does anyone know why this is working differently (could it be a basic settings difference)?

I do not want the code to highlight the text because when the text is highlighted and the macro tries to paste another table on the slide, it pastes the table in the highlighted cell, instead of as a new separate table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the shape in fact contains a table, try looping through each cell within the table using the Cell method of the Table object...

```
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long

With oShape.Table
    For lRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
        For lCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
            .Cell(lRow, lCol).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 20
        Next lCol
    Next lRow
End With
```

Comment: I've occasionally seen situations where changing a font's size causes Windows to render it as though its boldness/weight changed. It may be a display issue, in other words. What happens if you make the same change to the font size by hand?  Same effect?

Comment: That's essentially the loop that I'm using (I just posted the condensed line for simplicity) but the main issue is that one one computer, it changes the font size without needing to highlight the contents of the cell, and on another computer running the same version of ppt and excel, it does highlight the cell contents.

If I change the font size by hand I would either select the whole table and change the font size of the entire table at once, or if I changed the font size cell by cell, then I would need to highlight the contents of each cell since there isn't a way to click on a cell

Comment: Is that the exact line of code that you're using?  If so, you should get an error, since Cell is not a member of the Rows object.